# 'proleptic_gregorian' to date in netCDF4

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file with a time variable which is represented as 'proleptic_gregorian'. I want to use the `num2date` function to convert this into the Gregorian date.

I am currently trying this

```
import netCDF4 as nc
from netCDF4 import num2date, date2num

#read in the file
ncfile_o = Dataset(input_netcdf_file, 'r', format="NETCDF4")
```

this has the variables:

```
odict_keys(['time', 'time_bnds', 'lon', 'lat', 'landCoverFrac'])
```

I will now get the time information:

```
#time dimension
nctime = ncfile_o.variables['time'][:]
t_unit = ncfile_o.variables['time'].units   

t_cal = ncfile_o.variables['time'].calendar
```

Here `t_cal` is 'proleptic_gregorian' while `t_unit` is  'years since 1860-1-15 00:00:00'.  `nctime` looks something like this:

```
array([1.45698925,   2.45698925, 151.45698925, 152.45698925)]
```

I then try to turn it to dates like so:

```
datevar = []

datevar.append(num2date(nctime,units = t_unit,calendar = t_cal))
```

but this fails with:

```
ValueError: unsupported time units
```

Comment: Perhaps unit `'years since 1860-1-15 00:00:00` is not supported? Can you try: `t_unit = 'years since 1860-01-15 00:00:00'` i.e. you set the time unit instead of reading it from file?

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same error

Comment: Years are not supported units in `num2date`. Either convert the times to another unit (seconds, minuts, hours or days) or calculate the date yourself using the values from file and knowing the time unit.